# can't seem to run this code. trying to use tuples in class objects. i'm new to python.can anyone point me in the right direction?

Tags: python, class, tuples

```py
class Line:

    def __init__(self, coor1, coor2):
        self.coor1 = coor1
        self.coor2 = coor2

    def distance(self):
        x1, y1 = self.coor1
        x2, y2 = self.coor2
        return ((x2-x1)**2 + (y2-y1)**2)**0.5

    def slope(self):
        x1, y1 = self.coor1
        x2, y2 = self.coor2
        return ((y2-y1)/(x2-x1))


coor1 = (3, 2)
coor2 = (8, 10)

li = Line(coor1, coor2)
li.distance()
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Maybe you wanted `print(li.distance())` ?

Comment: when i run the code in vscode it returns nothing

Comment: Your code is fine. You didn't *do* anything with the distance in the last line. Perhaps you intended to print it?

Comment: yeah it worked. but in the jupyter notebook  we dont need print(). can you tell me why?

Comment: When you type code directly into a shell, you get instant feedback. That isn't the way *running* code works. For that to have an effect -- you have to have the code that you write explicitly have the intended effect.

Comment: thanks @JohnColeman

Answer (score 0):

try this one on jupyter notebook

```
print("result: {}".format(li.distance()))
```